# How can I make my element take the full screen and disable the scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I want to make my children div take the remaining space of the screen and disable the scrolling option, because I'm using PanZoom, I want the children's div to be always 100& the screen

```
<div class="parent">
    <menu> ... </menu>
    <div class="children"> ​
        <panzoom></panzoom> //the image can change size, height etc.
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use

```
children  {
    height : 100%
}
```

But with PanZoom, the div is bigger and the scroll option apears.

Answer (score 2):

I'm honestly not sure exactly what you mean, your question is a little unclear, but, here's a possible answer.

If you want to make an element truly full-screen, you shouldn't just set the height to 100%, you need to consider the user's screen, like so:

```
.element {
   height: 100vh;     // sets the height to the full screen view height
   width: 100vw;      // sets the width to the full screen view width
   overflow: hidden;  // hides scrolling
}
```

Comment: Yes ! Sorry... that what I was trying to do. But, my element now I have an other problem. My element takes 110% of the screen. Because I'm using Vuetify and I'm inside an <v-main> so it takes only the full height of the view and not of the screen. Can I do something like : height : 100vh - menu.height ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the scrollbar to appear you can do

```
.children {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```